# Splitting a dataframe's column by ';' copying all static rows and doing math on others

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe that has been read from a CSV. It has 36 columns and 3000+ rows. I want to split the dataframe on a column that contains items separated by a semicolon.

It is purchasing data and has mostly rows I would want to just copy down for the split; for example: Invoice Number, Sales Rep, etc. That is the first step and I have found many answers for this on SO, but none that solve for the second part.

There are other columns: Quantity, Extended Cost, Extended Price, and Extended Gross Profit that would need to be recalculated based on the split. The quantity, for the rows with values in the column in question, would need to be 1 for each item in the list; the subsequent columns would need to be recalculated based on that column.

See below for an example DF:

[image: example data]

How would I go about this?

A lot of implementations use `df.split(';')` and some use of `df.apply`, but unfortunately I am not understanding the process from front to back.

Edit: This is the output I am looking for:
[Proposed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbNlj.png)

Comment: are you able to show a textual example of your intended and expected output?

Comment: `df.column.str.split(';', expand=True)` simply split a column at each ';'

Comment: @Datanovice I have updated the post with a desired output.

Comment: @BenoitdeMenthière - This does not work.

Comment: please provide a copy paste of the df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas 0.25.1+ you can use `explode`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Quantity':[6,50,25,4]
                  ,'Column in question':['1;2;3;4;5;6','','','7;8;9;10']
                  ,'Price':['$1.00','$10.00','$0.10','$25.00']
                  ,'Invoice Close Date':['9/3/2019','9/27/2019','9/18/2019','9/30/2019']})

df_out = df.assign(ciq=df['Column in question'].str.split(';')).explode('ciq')\
           .drop('Column in question', axis=1)\
           .rename(columns={'ciq':'Column in question'})

df_out['Quantity'] = (df_out['Quantity'] / df_out.groupby(level=0)['Quantity'].transform('size'))

df_out
```

Output:

```
   Quantity   Price Invoice Close Date Column in question
0       1.0   $1.00           9/3/2019                  1
0       1.0   $1.00           9/3/2019                  2
0       1.0   $1.00           9/3/2019                  3
0       1.0   $1.00           9/3/2019                  4
0       1.0   $1.00           9/3/2019                  5
0       1.0   $1.00           9/3/2019                  6
1      50.0  $10.00          9/27/2019                   
2      25.0   $0.10          9/18/2019                   
3       1.0  $25.00          9/30/2019                  7
3       1.0  $25.00          9/30/2019                  8
3       1.0  $25.00          9/30/2019                  9
3       1.0  $25.00          9/30/2019                 10
```

Details:

First, create a column containing a list using `str.split` and `assign`.
Next, use `explode` then `rename` new column to old name after `drop`.

Comment: Scott, that does 75-85% of what I want to do - It just does not take the quantity from 6 down to 1 for each of the lines as the quantity now adds up to 36 and the extended prices/margins would also be duplicated rather than divided by the new quantities.

Comment: Add `df_out['Quantity'] = (df_out['Quantity'] / df_out.groupby(level=0)['Quantity'].transform('size'))`  See updated solution.  I didn't notice that in the output.

Comment: @ZKING And, you'll have to that same to other columns where you want to distribute amount over new rows.

Comment: This works! The only issue is (something that I did not foresee) that there is a semicolon after the last item in the field. I need to ignore that. Is there a way that if the field is not null to remove the last character in it before the split?

Comment: If the semicolon is always there, then yes...  `df['Column in question'].str[:-1].str.split(';')`  slice remove the last character like this.